# CentOS 6.2 black screen...help

Tags: centos, interface

I'm facing some problems with the CentOS graphical interface.

When I try to reboot the machines, it seems everything okay. I can connect to the machine through `ssh` from other machine and it has no problem with using it.
However, the screen on the actual machine (CentOS 6.2) shows me a black screen after the CentOS logo disappears.

It should show me the login screen but nothing is on the screen.

- Can anyone know what would be the problem here?
- Can I try to re-install the graphical interface again? If so, how?

Comment: use `egrep "EE" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `egrep "WW" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` Of course you'll get about two lines for each command, Because the given file have comment for `WW` and `EE` at top of file, please `troubleshoot` yourself, It's easy.

Comment: Is this in a Virtual Machine or Bare metal? If bare metal, what is your graphics adapter?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use ALT-F1, ALT-F2, ... (it might be CTL-ALT-F1, ...) to switch the virtual console using the console keyboard.  Screen 1 should always give a text login.  If that doesn't work, and you don't see boot messages on the console, there could be a bigger issue to solve.

In order to reconfigure X, try the `system-config-display` mentioned here:

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-x.html

You can also try the `setup` command mentioned here:

http://www.centos.org/docs/2/rhl-gsg-en-7.2/s1-q-and-a-xconfig.html

This page is for 7.2, but I believe the commands are the same for 6.2.

The following page shows the command `Xorg -configure`.  I would test it on my CentOS server, but I don't have access right now.

https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=38475

It sounds likely that the X-windows setup is not configured right - whether it's the type of display adapter, amount of display memory, or other setting.

Comment: `Xorg -configure` is sufficient for Cent 6.2, 6.3 and 6.4.

Comment: I just tried `Xorg -configure` and it complained because I already had another X server running.  So, I tried `system-config-display`, and that seems like a good one to try.

Comment: All links are not valid now!